# Perl: get() from LWP::Simple is obsolete?

Tags: perl, get

I just wanted to fetch data with the function get, but it always return undef, so I am wondering if this method still work ? Thanks for your feedback.

Example of code:

```
my $content = get("https://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/?query=KZS17205.1&format=tab&columns=entry%20name");

print $content;
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It does not return undef when I run it. https://i.imgur.com/NhlZ5xs.png

Comment: weird. I have this error:
Use of uninitialized value $content

Comment: Does `perl -MLWP::Protocol::https -e 1` return an error message? If yes, then you do not have support for the `https:` protocol. Please install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https)

Comment: BTW: your URL also supports `http:` protocol (both return the same answer). If it works with that, then you are missing `https:` support or there are some issues with the SSL handshake.

Comment: While not obsolete, you've discovered the reason it shouldn't be used: It's impossible to tell what went wrong. Best to use LWP::UserAgent; it's not any longer

Answer (score 2):

If the function was obsolete, then that would be clearly documented somewhere.

I see you're trying to get an `https` URL. Does it work if you try to get an `http` one?

You need to do a little more work in order to use LWP::Simple with `https`. This is described in the [README.SSL](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/libwww-perl-6.36/README.SSL) that comes with the LWP distribution. Currently, it says this:

> As of libwww-perl v6.02 you need to install the LWP::Protocol::https
>   module from its own separate distribution to enable support for
>   https://... URLs for LWP::UserAgent.
>
> This makes it possible for that
>   distribution to state the required dependencies as non-optional.  See
>   https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=66838 for further
>   discussion why we ended up with this solution.

So the solution is (almost certainly) to install [LWP::Protocol::https](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::Protocol::https).